Capture beginning of a line in a listing delimiter in order to style diff files
I am trying to display diff files in a listing. Each added line should be green and each removed line red.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{diff}
{
moredelim=[l][\color{green}]{+},
moredelim=[l][\color{red}]{-},
moredelim=[l][\color{yellow}]{\@\@},
deletestring=[d]",
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=diff]
diff --git a/main.go b/main.go
index eebf006..d1b9aa4 100644
--- a/main.go
+++ b/main.go
@@ -4,15 +4,14 @@ import (
    "fmt"
 )
 
+func main() {
+   fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
+   fmt.Println(fib(10))
+}
+
 func fib(n int) int {
    if n < 2 {
        return n
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
 }
-
-
-func main() {
-   fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
-   fmt.Println(fib(10))
-}

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

Which results in:

Here, characters that appear in the middle of a line are also counted as delimiter. Is there a way to specify that the delimiter has to be at the beginning of a line (i.e. like the regex ^+ would ensure)?

You can use comment of type f. From the listing manual:

morecomment=[f][commentstyle][⟨n=preceding columns⟩]⟨delimiter⟩
The delimiter starts a comment line if and only if it appears on a fixed
column-number, namely if it is in column n (zero based).

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{diff}
{
  morecomment=[f][\color{green}][0]{+},
  morecomment=[f][\color{red}][0]{-},
  morecomment=[f][\color{yellow}][0]{\@\@},
  deletestring=[d]",
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=diff]
diff --git a/main.go b/main.go
index eebf006..d1b9aa4 100644
--- a/main.go
+++ b/main.go
@@ -4,15 +4,14 @@ import (
    "fmt"
 )

+func main() {
+   fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
+   fmt.Println(fib(10))
+}
+
 func fib(n int) int {
    if n < 2 {
        return n
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
 }
-
-
-func main() {
-   fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
-   fmt.Println(fib(10))
-}

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


